# Tourist visa Canada without invitation letter?

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, tourist-visas, applications

I would like to know if there is a possibility for me to get  a tourist visa for Canada.

I have no invitation letter from anyone from Canada. I have travelled to the UK last year (July 2018) and I also visited Europe (Nov 2017).  Should I apply without having an invitation letter, or do I have to wait until I arrange invitation letter somehow?  If I should apply without having invitation letter then how much funds should I keep on my personal and current account?  I have an IT company here in India.

Comment: You don't need an invitation letter. Feel free to apply without one, if you have previous travel history, that should be beneficial towards the visa decision.

Comment: Thanks nikhil, but how much funds do I need? And I also get to know that these days Canada is refusing visitor visa Frequently

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you should not try to target a particular number when it comes to money. You should truthfully share what your current income and bank balances are and let the Canadian authorities make the determination on the eligibility. Funds parking is a common reason for visa refusals.

The most important thing that you need to demonstrate is that you have strong ties to India and you will be able to afford a trip to Canada with your current financial situation.

Comment: Eligibility criteria are here https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html It clearly states the amount of money needed depends on how long you plan to stay and how you’ll be accommodated during your visit. It also explains when you may be asked to provide an invitation letter.

Answer (score 6):

**You do not need an invitation letter to visit Canada.** Millions of people visit Canada without one. If someone has actually invited You to Canada they should send a letter, but if nobody has it does not matter.

**There is no set amount of money you need in your accounts.** They want to see that you have the money to pay for your visit of course. But they also want to see that your long term finances are such that spending money on the trip makes financial sense for you - for example that it is not an excessive amount relative to your income and expenditure. They also want to see no unexpected undocumented large transfers.